# Format and slice arrays with Python - prepare data for linear regression

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I know this is quite a basic question, but I am struggling a bit to format a tuple properly.
I have a csv file whose head is:

```
id   x1  x2  x3  y1 y2
 1   23  45  31  2  5
 2   34  5   21  3  12
 3   234 4   26  4  20
....
```

I am building a multi target linear regression model (I will use MultiOutputRegressor from scikit learn), so I want to to split data into X (which will then be splitted in training set and test set) and target Y. I import the csv like this:

```
with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
```

so I get a list of arrays. But how do I get access to elements in the array? My X set would be all the values of the fields x1, x2, x3 (then I would select some rows of X to build Xtrain); my Y set would be all the values of y1,y2.
My final goal is something like:

```
X= [[23 45 31]
    [34 5 21]
    [234 4 26]
    ...]

Y=[[2,5]
   [3,12]
   [4,20] 
   ...]
```

How can I achieve this?
Alternatively: how can I group the data structured as I said in a sparse matrix, which is a valid argument for scikit learn's linear regression function?

Comment: Have you looked at pandas (and numpy)?

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate arrays with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(data)    # Transform list to numpy array
data = data[1:,]         # Keep all lines except the header (first line)
y_col_index = 3
X = data[:,:y_col_index] # Select the first columns
Y = data[:,y_col_index:] # Select the last columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Victor Daplasse's answer is probably more straightforward, but I always prefer to use pandas to read and pre-process csv files.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = np.array(data[['x1', 'x2', 'x3']])
Y = np.array(data[['y1', 'y2']])
```